# Country not dispalyed in grid after overriding grid customer magento 2

Tags: magento2, countries

I have overrided the grid customer I can see all the value of attributes except the country I don't know why this behavior this is a part of grid code:

```
<column name="billing_country_id" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select" sortOrder="80">
            <settings>
                <filter>select</filter>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Country</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
```

and this is a part of the code of the di.xml

```
<virtualType name="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">customer_grid_flat</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

and this is a screenshot of the result:

Comment: Did you try to reindex after changes?

Comment: yes without hope

Comment: did you have solution?